# Boolean of one element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
<main class="ok">My text</main>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    if ( $('body').not('main.ok') ) {
    // or if ( Boolean ( $('main.ok') ) == false ) {

         // Main element not available
         alert (' Main element with "OK Class" not available ');

    } else {

         alert (' Main element with "OK Class" available ');

    }

});

</script>
```

but this code Doesn't work !

and alert

> Main element with "OK Class" not available

So what would u guys suggest me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

> Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.

```
$('body main').length && $('body main').hasClass('ok')
```

**CODE**

```
if ($('body main').length && $('body main').hasClass('ok')) {
    alert(' Main element with "OK Class" available ');
} else {
    alert(' Main element with "OK Class" not available ');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[**not()**](http://api.jquery.com/not/) returns a jQuery object. Try adding `length` to your condition and use [**find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead

```
if ( !$('body').find('main.ok').length )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create element selector along with `.length` to check if element exists or not:

```
if ($('body main.ok').length) {
  alert (' Main element with "OK Class" not available ');
} else {
  alert (' Main element with "OK Class" available ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use `body`? you just use: `$("main.ok").length`:

```
alert($("main.ok").length 
? 'Main element with "OK Class" available'
: 'Main element with "OK Class" not available');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ( $('body main').hasClass('ok') ) {
         alert (' Main element with "OK Class" not available ');
    } else {
         alert (' Main element with "OK Class" available ');
    }

});
```